# Ext JS - Grid when applied with filter leaves empty/blank sections in grid

Tags: extjs, grid, store

For example, when I apply a filter the grid area looks like this:

> - (Top of grid)
>
>   - blank area
>   - blank area
>   - blank area
>   - row w/ info
>   - row w/info
>   - (Bottom of grid)

I looked for a refresh option that would reload the view and adjust to the new store, however I failed to find anything that worked.
I currently use this to load the page after filter

> statusStore.loadPage(1)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a known general issue. You should post your relevant code to get useful answers.

Comment: Well its 1608 lines of code. Let me see if i can find the relevance

Comment: What Ext JS version are you using? I had quite a few headaches of that kind with the early versions of Ext JS 4.

Comment: im using a version of 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refresh the Grid View after apply the filter:

sencha api: [refresh view](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.view.View-method-refresh)

```
gridView.refresh();
```

Comment: I put in a listener, and on load I used (gridname).refresh(); and it seems to work. thank you.